# unity-tweak-tool: Why does it depend on mobile apps like webbrowser-app etc.?

Tags: dependencies, webapps, unity-tweak-tool

I want to install `unity-tweak-tool` on a relatively fresh install of ubuntu 16.04. In console `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool --no-install-recommends` shows the following dependencies:

```
Die folgenden zusätzlichen Pakete werden Installiert **[these additional packages are going to be installed]**
  libandroid-properties1 libhardware2 libhybris libhybris-common1 libmedia1 liboxideqt-qmlplugin
  liboxideqtcore0 liboxideqtquick0 libqt5positioning5 libunity-webapps0
  qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel qml-module-qt-labs-settings qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts
  qml-module-ubuntu-web qtdeclarative5-accounts-plugin qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin
  unity-webapps-common unity-webapps-qml unity-webapps-service webapp-container webbrowser-app
Vorgeschlagene Pakete: **[recommended packages]**
  xul-ext-unity | unity-chromium-extension qtdeclarative5-online-accounts-client0.1
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-content1 qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-download-manager0.1
  qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts-client
Die folgenden NEUEN Pakete werden installiert: 
  libandroid-properties1 libhardware2 libhybris libhybris-common1 libmedia1 liboxideqt-qmlplugin
  liboxideqtcore0 liboxideqtquick0 libqt5positioning5 libunity-webapps0
  qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel qml-module-qt-labs-settings qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts
  qml-module-ubuntu-web qtdeclarative5-accounts-plugin qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin
  unity-tweak-tool unity-webapps-common unity-webapps-qml unity-webapps-service webapp-container
  webbrowser-app
0 aktualisiert, 22 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 67 nicht aktualisiert.
Es müssen noch 1.503 kB von 34,8 MB an Archiven heruntergeladen werden.
Nach dieser Operation werden 135 MB Plattenplatz zusätzlich benutzt.
Möchten Sie fortfahren? [J/n] n
Abbruch.
```

Why does unity-tweak-tool need the alternative browser and the other apps? Does this mean that the program is intended to run on ubuntu touch devices?

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason (ask or bug them) unity-tweak-tool depends on unity-webapps-common. The progression of deps from there go as such -

unity-webapps-common > unity-webapps-service > webapp-container > webbrowser-app

Whether the tweak tool runs on ubuntu touch devices don't know or care as it's pretty much a dead dog.